# Compare keys from json service response

Tags: ios, ios5, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I am getting a json service to which I want to do comparison checks on the values of certain keys. For example I have a key 'status' in json array, but I am unable to do a comparison check on its value.
The response is like:

```
{"status":400,"response":"No cast found"}
```

I want to do something like:

```
if([jsonDict objectForKey:@"status"] == @"400"){
..
}
```

but the check wont work, whats the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be two things:

If **[jsonDict objectForKey:@"status"]** is giving you a NSString, then    the correct way to compare is:

```
if([[jsonDict objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"400"])
```

If  **[jsonDict objectForKey:@"status"]** is giving you a NSNumber,    or    NSDecimalNumber:

```
if([[jsonDict objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:400])
```

Comment: more elaborated than my answer. I like that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
if([jsonDict objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString @"400"){
..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in this way:

```
if([[jsonDict objectForKey:@"status"] intValue] == 400){
//your code here
}
```